# Google Speech to Text Simultaneous command display

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am trying to integrate speech to text in android using RecognizerIntent. I want that whatever commands I am speaking should be simultaneously displayed in Google canvas as in Google Now invocation using OK Google.

When we speak in OK Google followed by any speech then it gets simultaneously displayed in the card using nlp i guess. Similarly i want that when i use speech to text using Recognizer Intent it should simultaneouly keep displaying the text spoken.

Does anyone knows any API or library to implement it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: Its just that when we use speech to text in android, we cannot see what the user is speaking or commanding. But when we give commands to OK Google it even displays what commands are being spoken for instance if i say hi there it displays hi there simultaneously. How can we achieve this programatically when implementing speech to text using RecognizerIntents?

Comment: You need to use the SpeechRecognizer implementation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html